# .map on an array of objects within another array: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: reactjs

I'm using React/Redux, and having an issue parsing through the array of objects of the query I'm receiving. The array I'm trying to parse is contained in its own array that looks like this.

```
{map: "TheIsland", password: false, raw: {…}, maxplayers: 30, …}players:[{…}]....
```

The array "players" is what I'm having problems with. I receive and display most of query data just fine, but when trying to run .map on "players" to blast the "name" property to some text, I receive the error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

As my component mounts I set players as an empty array in the constructor to account for running .map before the query has returned. When I console.log the response upon receiving it, "players" looks like this,

```
players: Array(3) 0:{name: "Jones", score: 0, time: 1573.2921142578125} 1:{name: "Matt", score: 0, time: 1348.6531982421875} 2:{name: "Skippy", score: 0, time: 285.5899963378906} length:3
```

I can neither grab any player info nor the array length.

Here's my full component.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchStatus } from "./../actions";

import "./arkStats.css";

class ArkStats extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      players: []
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.fetchStatus();
  }

  renderPlayers() {
    return console.log(this.props.status);
    <div>
      {this.props.status.players.map((player, index) =>
        <p key={index}>
          Hello, {player.name}!
        </p>
      )}
    </div>
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.status.name}
        {this.props.status.map}
        {this.renderPlayers()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps({ status }) {
  return { status };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchStatus })(ArkStats);
```

Comment: Can you give me an example of the props that the function receives? It can be dummy data, I just need a real example

Comment: The very first code entry is the console.log as found in Chrome's console. {map: "TheIsland", password: false, raw: {…}, maxplayers: 30, …}players:[{…}]....
With the exception of the periods at the end. The third code entry is what "players" looks like when that console.log is opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map can't read players because this is an object with keys. If you take a look at `players:` you will see 0:{}, 1:{}, etc..

If the data is stored like this, you should be mapping like this.

```
  renderPlayers() {
    return Object.keys(players).map((key, index) => {
       return(
          <p key={ index }> Hello, { players[key].name } </p>
       );
    });
  }
```

Comment: I think the OP clearly mentioned that players was an array. The only thing that could have gone wrong would be the status prop that was passed (its undefined)

Comment: He mentioned that but he also mentioned how players look like. According to that, that's how you should be mapping.

Comment: He mentioned how players look like by representing an array.            players: Array(3) 0:{name: "Jones", score: 0, time: 1573.2921142578125} , where 0 is the index of the array. He is not trying to map each array index individually. Hope that clarifies :)